# Sifting through Node.js, Express and mysql module

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I'm trying to work through integrating the express framework for node.js and the mysql module https://npmjs.org/package/mysql.  I have a simple application setup (by using the express command line) and I also have a module declared for working with some of the database properties.

My DB module is setup like this:

```
app.js
node_modules
|___db
     |
     node_modules
           |___mysql
```

With the mysql module setup to be a dependency of the db module.

In my index.js for the db module I have some module exports setup to be accessed by the application:

```
/*
 * Connection params for database
 */

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database',
});

var connect = connection.connect(function(err){
  if(!err){
        console.log("You are connected to the database.");
  }
  else{
        throw err;
  }
});

var end = connection.end(function(err){
  if(!err){
        console.log("Mysql connection is terminated.")
  }
  else{
        throw err;
  }
});

module.exports = {
  connect: connect,
  connection: connection,
  end: end,
}
```

In my app.js file I am requiring my db module and specifying some routes. I'm also trying to use a route middleware function (estDb) inside the app.get method for the clients route:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , clients = require('./routes/clients')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , db = require('db');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

var estDb = function(req, res, next){
  db.connect;
  db.connection.query("SELECT * FROM Table", function(err, results){
        if(!err){
          req.results = results;
        }
        else{
          throw err;
        }
  });
  db.end;
  next();
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/clients', estDb, clients.view);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

**The Problem**
I'm having is that it seems that my db functions (my module exports) are getting called when I start the application as I'm getting the log:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
You are connected to mysql.
Mysql connection is terminated.
```

**NOT** when the url `http://localhost/clients` is requested (which is what I have the route defined as).  As you can see, it is firing the db.connect() and the db.end() right after the console logs the "Express server listening on port 3000" message -- which leads me to believe it's firing from the custom db module I'm using.  Subsequently, when I go to the route `http://localhost/clients` I get an error:

```
500 Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
```

If I remove the connection.end() function from the db module, I can connect to the database and retrieve results; however, if I reload the page and try to load the results again, I get an error:

```
Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake
```

I don't understand why my module exports are firing when I start the application? I think this is where I'm getting in trouble.

Any suggestions or help on this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why my module exports are firing when I start the application? 
>   I think this is where I'm getting in trouble.

I believe this is happening because of this piece of code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database',
});
```

In here you are actually *connecting to the database*, rather than *defining a function than when called will connect to the database*.

Comment: I would also look at the suggestions that Chris made regarding the missing parentheses in estDb.

Comment: Hey Hector, thanks for checking into this.  You pointed me in the right direction by forcing me to look at what I had declared in my db module.  The trouble I was running into was not actually the `createConnection()` method you had pointed out above, but the ensuing `connect()` and `end()` methods.  I thought that by setting `connect = connection.connect()` it would store the function in the variable, but you were right to point out that it needs to be `connect = function(connection){ connection.connect(); }`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Your log message are not the ones you get from that code (there is no "You are connected to mysql")!? Try the following:

```
db.connect;
```

should be

```
db.connect();
```

because you want to execute the function. You'd also want to wait for the query to finish before executing `next()`

```
var estDb = function(req, res, next){
  db.connect();
  db.connection.query("SELECT * FROM Table", function(err, results){
        if(!err){
          req.results = results;
          next();
        }
        else{
          throw err;
        }
  });
  db.end();
}
```

EDIT: What happens here is that the code in your `db` module executes right away when you require it. What you want do do is this:

```
var connect = function(){
  connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!err){
      console.log("You are connected to the database.");
    }
    else{
      throw err;
    }
  })
};
```

You can then call `db.connect()` as shown in my post (same for `end()`). If you put `db.connect` in one line (without the parenthesis), **nothing** will happen.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your answer.  You were correct in executing the `next();` function in the callback of the query, instead of outside the query. The functions however, are referencing an export variable from the module (with coincidentally I have set to a function) so those should remain `db.connect` and `db.end` -- Just to make sure I ran the app with `db.connect()` and it said that the method was undefined.  If you are calling directly from mysql module you would be correct by using `connection.connect()`, but in this instance I'm exporting the `connect()` method as a variable.